# Killing developer's debugging connection with server

Tags: java, debugging, weblogic

Please don't mark it as a duplicate of how to kill process running on server. This is question how to detach developer from port so that another one could attach.

Is it possible to kill somehow a connection to a debug port?

Our server exposes debug port: 5551

```
$netstat -an | grep 5551
```

Gives me:

```
tcp        0     55 (serverIp):4442         (developerIp):51237         ESTABLISHED
```

This blocks the application. Developer went to coffee. If I want to kill this session I must restart whole server.

Is it possible to kill only this connection and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but look into [tcpkill or cutter](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/kill-tcp-connection-using-linux-netstat.php) which kills the connection:

```
tcpkill -i eth0 port 4442
```

Comment: tcpkill not found, Red Hat 4.4.7

Comment: Looks like you have to separately install it (as `dsniff`):   http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25071763/dir/redhat_el_6/com/dsniff-2.4-0.17.b1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html  @michealAtmi

Comment: Mac Terminal Users may want to see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/kill-tcp-connections-on-a-mac-in-terminal/134733